# Does this group action construction have a name?

Tags: terminology, group-actions

Let $G \curvearrowright X$ be a group action. Then $G \curvearrowright X \times X$ through $g \cdot (x, y) = (g \cdot x, g \cdot y)$. I am interested if this 'diagonal' action and its orbits have a special name.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, your guess "diagonal action" is a common name for this kind of group action.

Comment: I agree.  In fact, in papers of mine, I've referred to a more general scenario as the diagonal action:  If $G$ acts on both $X$ and $Y$, then $G$ acts on $X\times Y$ in a similar fashion.  In case it matters, I usually denote the orbit space as $X\times_G Y$ in this case.